# Bash edit file and keep last 500 lines

Tags: bash, logging, tail

I am looking to create a cron job that opens a directory loops through all the logs i have created and deletes all lines but keep the last 500 for example.

I was thinking of something along the lines of

`tail -n 500 filename > filename`

Would this work?

I also not sure how to loop through a directory in bash.

Comment: See the other answers, but your sample `tail` line executes like this: 1) the shell opens filename for output and truncates it to zero length 2) tail runs, sees an empty file and 3) writes nothing into the now empty filename. The MYYN's answer shows how you avoid that, but even that bombs if `tail` encounters an error. Don't reinvent logrotate that tanascius recommends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about using [**logrotate**](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html).
It will not do what you want (delete all lines but the last 500), but it can take care of logfiles which are bigger than a certain size (normally by comressing the old ones and deleting them at some point). Should be widely available.

Answer (score 14):

If log file to be truncated is currently open by some services, then using mv as in previous answers will disrupt those services.  This can be easily overcome by using cat instead:

```
tail -n 1000 myfile.log > myfile.tmp
cat myfile.tmp > myfile.log
```

Comment: saved my bacon... twice! this is almost like a right of passage to learn when you are faced with a `df -h` at 99% and 6 mins before a demo.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the easiest and fastest way is using a variable:

```
LASTDATA=$(tail -n 500 filename)
echo "${LASTDATA}" > filename
```

Comment: for those in a hurry like I was, those are curly brackets around the variable name...

Answer (score 1):

```
DIR=/path/to/my/dir # log directory
TMP=/tmp/tmp.log # temporary file
for f in `find ${DIR} -type f -depth 1 -name \*.log` ; do
  tail -n 500 $f > /tmp/tmp.log
  mv /tmp/tmp.log $f
done
```

Comment: `for foo in $(find)` is a bad habit to develop. Either use `find | while read` or globbing. And the `mv` should be conditional on the success of the `tail`.

Comment: @Dennis: thanks - can you explain why `for foo in $(find ...)` is a bad habit ?

Comment: If there are filenames with spaces, it will see those as multiple separate names.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you loop over files in a directory, e.g. like this:

```
cd target/directory

for filename in *log; do
    echo "Cutting file $filename"
    tail -n 500 $filename > $filename.cut
    mv $filename.cut $filename
done
```

Comment: The `mv` should be conditional on the success of the `tail`.